# The correct way to use NOT IN in a mysql query

Tags: php, sql

I have a mysql query that throws an error  which I'm guessing is because of my judicious use of the phrase "NOT IN":

```
$sqlGetCountry = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE country='$country' AND CURTIME() > time AND '$state' NOT IN state ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 20");
$sqlNumCountry = mysqli_num_rows($sqlGetCountry);
```

I have a table with city, state, and country and I'm basically trying to find the queries where a given state ($state in this case, which could be Texas, Hawaii, etc.) is not in the results. I get the error:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Anybody have a clue?

Comment: Or are you trying to find rows not matching `$state`? Or if `$state` doesn't exist in the entire table?

Comment: What is `state`? Is it a column? A table?

Comment: I read your question 5 times now, and I think you'd come across a lot clearer with some sample data and desired output

Comment: "I have a table with city, state, and country". state is a row in the table locations. city, state, and country are all rows in the table locations. @Michael, I'm trying to find rows not matching $state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a table to `in`, but you can pass a subquery:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    locations 
WHERE   country='$country' 
        AND CURTIME() > time 
        AND '$state' NOT IN (select state from state)
ORDER BY 
       time desc 
LIMIT  20
```

Comment: Oddly, I get the same results.

Comment: On rereading the question, perhaps you mena `'$state' <> state`?  Otherwise it would help to add example in- and output, like @lc. suggests.

Comment: You are the man @Andomar. '$state' <> state works just fine. Gotta love you SQL gurus!